# rails - :joins sanitizing/substitution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, substitution

is it possible to specify parameters for :joins similar way as for :conditions?

here is an example (sql code is irrelevant)

```
named_scope :threads, {
  :joins => [" LEFT JOIN groups_messages gm ON messages.id=gm.message_id AND gm.group_id IN (?) ",@group_ids_array], 
  :conditions => ["creator_id=? AND messages.id IN (?)", current_user_id, @message_ids_array]
}
```

in this example parameters for :conditions would get inserted properly, but for :joins i would get an error

```
 Association named '  LEFT JOIN groups_messages gm ON messages.id=gm.message_id and gm.group_id IN (?) ' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

what function substitutes parameters for :conditions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [ActiveRecord::sanitize_sql_array](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002322) method.

```
ActiveRecord::sanitize_sql_array ['gm.group_id IN (?)', @group_ids_array]
```